# getting details and closing orders from shopify API

Tags: python, shopify

```
order = shopify.Order.find(151574820)

print order
```

This returns: `order(151574820)`

How do I get the details from the order? How would I go about modifying this order? I am new to the python shopify API but I just can't figure it out and the docs seem super minimal. Either that or I am not looking in the right place. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Docs for getting order details: http://docs.shopify.com/api/order#show & docs for closing an order: http://docs.shopify.com/api/order#close

Answer (score 2):

```
shopify.Order.get(shopify.Order.get_id(order))
```